# display can't show the image properly using rpi 4 with retropie

Tags: pi-4, display

I'm using an 8.9" 2k IPS lcd display connected to the raspberry pie 4 through a control board with HDMI. When I connect the display to a laptop with HDMI, the image is clear and has no problem (so not the lcd nor the control board is broken or anything) but when I try to use it with the rpi 4, it's always like that. My guess is that I sould calibrate the resolution but I'm not sure how to do that.

[image: the raspberry pi 4 with the control board]

[image: the display]

Comment: it isn't `pie` ..

Comment: We haven't the faintest idea WHAT OS or what you might have done although from the picture we can guess a Pi4. It might help if you plugged into the correct HDMI port.

Comment: PS You appear to have a cable with red & black wires plugged into 5V & 3.3V (although it is unclear WHAT it is connected to) - I see a dead Pi in the offing!